# How does refinement scope work?

Tags: ruby

This is essentially a snippet from Ruby Metaprogramming 2. In the section they gloss over this example but there isn't really an explanation.

```ruby
module MyRefinement
  refine MyClass do
    def my_method
      "refined"
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  def my_method
    "original"
  end

  def another_method
    my_method
  end
end

using MyRefinement

obj = MyClass.new

puts obj.my_method       #=> "refined"
puts obj.another_method  #=> "original"
```

Why doesn't the refinement apply when you call `my_method` from another method?

Comment: Read this https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/wiki/RefinementsSpec ... Me confused after reading the full page.

Answer (score 3):

It avoids "leaky" refinements, e.g., the refinement applies *specifically* to the method you refine.

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/11/30/ruby-2-0-refinements-in-practice/

Very near the bottom this functionality is explained; nutshell:

> [the] refinement should not leak [...]. If it did, it would mean that any call into any method could leak a refinement into that method, which is the opposite of the purpose of the feature.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that article. But for the answer, I still don't understand why `my_method` isn't being "refined" just because it's being called from another method. What if I wanted to refine it and then have all other methods inside that class use it?

Comment: @Uri Then you'd have to change your refinement. The bottom line is that this just isn't how refinements work. It isn't being refined because it's not in the lexical scope of your refinement; the linked article goes in to some further detail, but I'm not sure it'll get much clearer.

Comment: There is also this in the book, which I couldn't understand, "...even if you call `another_method` **after** using , the call to
`my_method` itself happens **before** using —so it calls the original, unrefined version
of the method.". Could you please explain what's meant by "the call to my_method itself happens before using"? How does it happen before?

Comment: Does it mean that the `another_method` is defined above the `using` so when we call `another_method` the `my_method` refinement is not active in that scope since `using` function takes place below that. That's how I interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

`refine` keyword use to Refinements of the class locally. It's mean we can monkey patch any method by refinement of the class.

In your case, the process of refine/redfined/monkey patch only active when the method get call directly. Also Refinements are lexical in scope. When control is transferred outside the scope the refinement is deactivated.

To get better insight, read the `scope` part of refinements from here: [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html)

Comment: This answer just states again what the OP observed, it is not really an explanation _why_ this happens.

Comment: @PatrickOscity there haven't any explanation in the referral link! ? Could you please read once again and then let me know where this is not correct!

Comment: Using my example, could you expand on what the `scope` would be during execution? I'm not understand where the scope changes.